# Sharepoint 2013 Javascript - Get List Fields

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am on a double learning curve with SharePoint 2013 development and JavaScript.

Please refer to below.

```
function GetListFields(listname, viewname, ResultCallBackFunction)
{
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = clientContext.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listname);
  if (viewname == "")
  {
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewname);
    var listFields = view.get_viewFields(); 
  }
  else
  {
    this.listFields = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");  
  } 
  clientContext.load(this.listFields);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onListFieldsQuerySucceeded, onListFieldsQueryFailed);


  function onListFieldsQuerySucceeded()
  {
    console.log(listFields.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title").get_internalName());

    var fldArray = new Array();
    var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
    while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
      var oField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
      fldArray.push(oField);
    }

    ResultCallBackFunction(fldArray);
  }

  function onListFieldsQueryFailed()
  {
    alert("Something went wrong. The End is Nigh.");
  }
}
```

The intent is to call *GetListFields* to return an array with the list's fieldnames. This returns an error "Unable to get property 'get_fields' of undefined or null reference" at the line "console.log....". Please note that this is for my debugging.

If I change the code for function *GetListFields* as follows:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listname);
if (viewname == "")
    viewname = "All Items";
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewname);
this.listFields = view.get_viewFields();
```

I DO get a result but this contains a field named 'LinkTitle' which I do not have in my list because I have renamed this. What am I missing?

Further to the above, I got an error when using

```
var listFields = ...
```

which fixed by doing

```
this.listFields = ...
```

but do not understand the difference.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I took a moment to test your code in my Sharepoint 2013 environment.

I made some changes and now it works.

You can see the resulting script bellow.

Here is some important information about the field names in the result array.

The names of the fields in the view returned by Sharepoint are the internal names and not the title of the field.

This is the reason why you get LinkTitle instead of the real title of your field.

When you create a field in the Sharepoint interface, Sharepoint create a title for the field and also an internal name based on the title.

For example, if I create a field named « my test field », Sharepoint will say the title of the field is « my test field » and the internal name is « my_x0020_test_x0020_field ».

```
<script>
function GetListFields(listname, viewname, ResultCallBackFunction)
{
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = clientContext.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listname);
  var listFields;
  var view;
  var defaultViewName = 'All Items';
  if (viewname === "")
  {
    viewname = defaultViewName;
  }
  view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewname);
  listFields = view.get_viewFields();

  clientContext.load(listFields);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onListFieldsQuerySucceeded, onListFieldsQueryFailed);

  function onListFieldsQuerySucceeded()
  {
    var fldArray = new Array();
    var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
    while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
      var oField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
      fldArray.push(oField);
    }

    ResultCallBackFunction(fldArray);
  }

  function onListFieldsQueryFailed()
  {
    alert("Something went wrong. The End is Nigh.");
  }
}

function MyCallBack(fieldArray) {
  for (var x=0;x<fieldArray.length;x++) {
    console.log(fieldArray[x]);
  }
}
</script>
<a id="callGetListFields" href="#" onclick="GetListFields('MyListName','MyViewName', MyCallBack);">Call function GetListFields</a>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for this.

Sorry I cannot up-vote the comment but the site reports the following: